# Ensure Office-js addin available in ribbon, sharepoint Word 2016

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, office-js, appsource, word-2016

I am deploying an Office.js add-in for MS word using sideloading, AppSource, and private sharepoint catalogs for Office 2016. In some cases, I've observed that once Word is restarted, the add-in vanishes from the ribbon and has to be re-added using the "My Add-ins" button in the ribbon.

Is it possible to ensure the add-in is always in the ribbon for a user, regardless if Word is restarted?